# Separator Added in my ASP.Net form does not show inside of my form

Tags: css, asp.net, styles

I am building a ASP.net form using bootstrap. I used the following code with styles to add a separator in my form.

```
<div id="ApprovedVenueGroup" class="hidden">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label for="locationAndPostalAddress" class="control-label col-xs-4">Address</label> 
        <div class="col-xs-8" id="ApprovedVenueContainer">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="hr-sect">Physical Address</div>                                                 


<div class="form-group required">
        <label for="locationAndPostalAddress" class="control-label col-xs-4">Address</label> 
    <div class="col-xs-8" id="PhysicalAddressContainer">

    </div>
</div>
```

I have used the below styles for the separator.

```
.hr-sect {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 8px 0px;
}
.hr-sect::before,
.hr-sect::after {
    content: "";
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    height: 1px;
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin: 0px 16px;
}
```

Unfortunately my separator shows out of my form. If I add a character as below  it will show correctly. Meaning the separator shows in the correct place. How can I resolve this. Please help.

```
<div id="ApprovedVenueGroup" class="hidden">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label for="locationAndPostalAddress" class="control-label col-xs-4">Address</label> 
        <div class="col-xs-8" id="ApprovedVenueContainer">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

**Char**
<div class="hr-sect">Physical Address</div>                                                 


<div class="form-group required">
        <label for="locationAndPostalAddress" class="control-label col-xs-4">Address</label> 
    <div class="col-xs-8" id="PhysicalAddressContainer">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a silly mistake. I used bootstrap for the the form. I forgot to define the bootstrap styling the code worked fine.

Address